# I am getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException thrown while using HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashset

How do i remove the key value pair in the code below comparing with elements in HashMap?

```
Map<BigDecimal, TransactionLogDTO> transactionLogMap = new HashMap<BigDecimal, TransactionLogDTO>();
for (BigDecimal regionID : regionIdList) {// Generation new logDTO
                                            // objects for each in scope
                                            // region
    transactionLogMap.put(regionID, new TransactionLogDTO());
}
Set<BigDecimal> inScopeActiveRegionIdSet = new HashSet<BigDecimal>();

for (PersonDTO personDTO4 : activePersons) {

    inScopeActiveRegionIdSet.add(personDTO4.getRegion());

}

for (BigDecimal bigDecimal : transactionLogMap.keySet()) {
    if (!inScopeActiveRegionIdSet.contains(bigDecimal)) {
        transactionLogMap.remove(bigDecimal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in these lines

```
for (BigDecimal bigDecimal : transactionLogMap.keySet()) {
    if(!inScopeActiveRegionIdSet.contains(bigDecimal)) {
        transactionLogMap.remove(bigDecimal);
    }
}
```

You are iterating through the `transactionLogMap` whilst also directly modifying the underlying `Collection` when you call `transactionLogMap.remove`, which is not allowed because the enhanced for loop cannot see those changes.

The correct solution is to use the `Iterator`:

```
Iterator<BigDecimal> it = transactionLogMap.keySet().iterator();//changed for syntax correctness
while (it.hasNext()) {
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = it.next();
    if(!inScopeActiveRegionIdSet.contains(bigDecimal)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

As per javadoc

> [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible

```
 transactionLogMap.remove(bigDecimal);
```

Instead of `for loop` use `Iterator` and call remove on iterator.

Example:

```
Iterator iter = transactionLogMap.keySet().iterator();
while(iter.hasNext())
{
iter.remove();
}
```

OR

You may consider using [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Note: Typed in code, use as reference. There may be syntax errors.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot remove items from a collection while you are iterating over it. This causes the exception you're getting.

When you call:

```
for(TypeX x: collectionOfX){ ... }
```

What happens under the hood is that you're creating an iterator for collectionOfX, and iterating until you explicitly break from the cycle or hasNext() for the iterator is false.

If you need to remove items from the collection during the iteration, you need to replace that `foreach` construct with an explicit call to the Iterator. Something like:

```
Iterator<BigDecimal> iter = transactionLogMap.keySet().iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
   BigDecimal bDecimal = iter.next();
   ...
   iter.remove(); //this will remove the current item from the collection, without raising an exception.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if `inScopeActiveRegionIdSet` is smaller in size, it might be shorter and faster to iterate it instead:

```
for (BigDecimal bigDecimal : inScopeActiveRegionIdSet) {
    transactionLogMap.remove(bigDecimal);
}
```