# Accurate data on a map accessed by many threads

Tags: java, data-structures, java-7, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to sort objects into five separate groups depending on a weight given to them at instantiation.

Now, I want to sort these objects into the five groups by their weights.  In order to do this, each one must be compared to the other.

Now the problem I'm having is these objects are added to the groups on separate worker threads.  Each one is sent to the synchronized sorting function, which compares against all members currently in the three groups, after an object has completed downloading a picture.

The groups have been set up as two different maps.  The first being a Hashtable, which crashes the program throwing an unknown ConcurrencyIssue.  When I use a ConcurrentHashMap, the data is wrong because it doesn't remove the entry in time before the next object is compared against the ConcurrentHashmap.  So this causes a logic error and yields groups that are sorted correctly only half of the time.

I need the hashmap to immediately remove the entry from the map before the next sort occurs...  I thought synchronizing the function would do this but it still doesn't seem to work.

Is there a better way to sort objects against each other that are being added to a datastructure by worker threads?  Thanks!  I'm a little lost on this one.

```
private synchronized void sortingHat(Moment moment) {
    try {
        ConcurrentHashMap[] helperList = {postedOverlays, chanl_2, chanl_3, chanl_4, chanl_5};

        Moment moment1 = moment;

        //Iterate over all channels going from highest channel to lowest
        for (int i = channelCount - 1; i > 0; i--) {

            ConcurrentHashMap<String, Moment> table = helperList[i];

            Set<String> keys = table.keySet();

            boolean mOverlap = false;

            double width = getWidthbyChannel(i);

            //If there is no objects in table, don't bother trying to compare...
            if (!table.isEmpty()) {

                //Iterate over all objects currently in the hashmap
                for (String objId : keys) {
                    Moment moment2 = table.get(objId);

                    //x-Overlap
                    if ((moment2.x + width >= moment1.x - width) ||
                            (moment2.x - width <= moment1.x + width)) {

                        //y-Overlap                           
                        if ((moment2.y + width >= moment1.y - width) ||
                                (moment2.y - width <= moment1.y + width)) {

                            //If there is overlap, only replace the moment with the greater weight.
                            if (moment1.weight >= moment2.weight) {
                                mOverlap = true;
                                table.remove(objId);
                                table.put(moment1.id, moment1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //If there is no overlap, add to channel anyway
            if (!mOverlap) {
                table.put(moment1.id, moment1);
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("SortingHat", e.toString());
    }
}
```

The `table.remove(objId)` is where the problems occur.  Moment A gets sent to sorting function, and has no problems.  Moment B is added, it overlaps, it compares against Moment A.  If Moment B is less weight than Moment A, everything is fine.  If Moment B is weighted more and A has to be removed, then when moment C gets sorted moment A will still be in the hashmap along with moment B.  And so that seems to be where the logic error is.

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723159/i-am-getting-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-thrown-while-using-hashma

Comment: Also, you can't sort a `Map` in java.  The interface doesn't promise to respect order.  There is a `SortedMap` interface, which would, based on a sorting method that you can supply.

Comment: Your description is unclear. Do you have five groups, or three (in one place you say three, others you say five)? What criteria do you use to define the groups? Is fixed (i.e. items less than 100 go to group 1, items less than 500 go to group 2, etc), or do you want five (or was it three) approximately equal sized groups, based on the entire list of objects? What is the desired final state (i.e. how many and what types of data structures do you want when the process is done)? Your description, and your code sample, address none of those questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having an issue with your synchronization.

The synchronize you use, will synchronize using the "this" lock. You can imagine it like this:

```
public synchronized void foo() { ... }
```

is the same as

```
public void foo() {
    synchronized(this) {
        ....
    }
}
```

This means, before entering, the current Thread will try to acquire "this object" as a lock. Now, if you have a worker Thread, that also has a synchronized method (for adding stuff to the table), they won't totally exclude each other. What you wanted is, that one Thread has to finish with his work, before the next one can start its work.

> The first being a Hashtable, which crashes the program throwing an unknown ConcurrencyIssue.

This problem accourse because it may happen, that 2 Threads call something at the same time. To illustrate, imagine one Thread calling put(key, value) on it and another Thread calling remove(key). If those calls get executed at the same time (like by different cores) what will be the resulting HashTable? Because noone can say for sure, a [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) will be thrown. Note: This is a verry simplyfied explanation!

> When I use a ConcurrentHashMap, the data is wrong because it doesn't remove the entry in time before the next object is compared against the ConcurrentHashmap

The ConcurrentHashMap is a utility, for avoiding said concurrency issues, it is not magical, multi functional, unicorn hunting, butter knife. It snynchronizes the mehtod calls, which results in the fact, that only one Thread can either add to or remove from or do any other work on the HashMap. It does not have the same functionallity as a Lock of some sort, which would result in the access over the map being allocated to on Thread.

There could be one Thread that wants to call add and one that want to call remove. The ConcurrentHashMap only limits those calls in the matter, that they can't happen at the same time. Which comes first? You have power over that (in this scenario). What you want is, that one thread has to finish with his work, before the next one can do its work.

What you realy need is up to you. The [java.util.concurrent package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) brings a whole arsenal of classes you could use. For example:

You could use a [lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) for each Map. With that, each Thread (either sorting/removing/adding or whatever) could first fetch the Lock for said Map and than work on that Map, like this:

```
public Worker implements Runnable {
    private int idOfMap = ...;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Lock lock = getLock(idOfMap);
        try {
            lock.lock();
            // The work goes here
            //...
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

The line lock.lock() would ensure, that there is no other Thread, that is currently working on the Map and modifing it, after the method call returns and this Thread will therefore have the mutial access over the Map. No one sort, before you are finished removing the right element.

Of course, you would somehow have to hold said locks, like in a data-object. With that being said, you could also utilize the Semaphore, synchronized(map) in each Thread or formulating your work on the Map in the form of Runnables and passing those to another Thread that calls all Runnables he received one by one. The possibilities are nearly endless. I personally would recommend on starting with the lock.