# Why getting ConcurrentModificationException in HashMap

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

I have a code like below to loop through the hashmap but I am getting error

> ConcurrentModificationException

```
for (String i : currentItems.keySet()) //I am hitting error in this line
   {
         items.put(i,currentItems.get(i));
         currentRoom.removeItem(i);
         System.out.println(items.get(i));
   }
```

I would appreciate any suggestion in the above.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. In particular, how do you initialize `currentItems` and `items`. Also, does `currentRoom.removeItem(i)` affect `currentItems`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Java does not allow modifying collections while iterating over them
2. For any use case requiring modification while iterating, please use [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723159/i-am-getting-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-thrown-while-using-hashma)